# How to execute tasks dynamically in Gradle 5?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

In gradle 5, the `execute()` method is removed. What is the quickest way to migrate a gradle 4 tasks. I cannot use `dependsOn` because execution is **dynamic** based on e.g. the environmentName or another condition:

```
task clearData() {
    doLast {
        if ( environmentName in nonProductionEnvironments ) {
            clearTask1.execute()
            clearTask2.execute()
        } else {
            throw new GradleException("Not allowed to clear data in this environment.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At what point is `environmentName` evaluated and can be used? Is it the result of another task?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `execute` method from tasks, but if it must be dynamic then I suggest adding a listener somewhere depending what you're trying to react to.

There are:

- Build listeners: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/BuildListener.html
- Task listeners: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html

There are more, but I believe one of those may solve your issue. Since `dependsOn` does not work for you, then doing whatever work you're trying to do as a `Task` does not sound like the right approach.